# Pressing tab in a contenteditable control using webkit

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I'm working with a contenteditable iframe that is being using for basic WYSIWYG editing. I've noticed a strange difference in the way that a Tab keypress event is handled between Chrome and Firefox.

When the document of the iframe has been configured using `designMode = 'On'`, a tab pressed inside the document will skip to the next control in Firefox (expected) but create the following pre white-spaced span in Chrome

```
<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre">   </span>
```

[Here's an example](http://codepen.io/Stumblor/pen/ymuLB).

Interestingly, when the body of the iframe is setup instead using `body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")`, which I assumed was the same approach done in a different way, both browsers work as i would expect; moving the focus to the next tab index.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only answer is "just because". Don't expect that there's a reason behind how something works in `contenteditable`. I experienced hundreds of times that no one really cared or had time to care about that. When you've got bugs like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941 which make contenteditable totally irritating for users on Chrome & Opera and which hasn't been even confirmed by developers throughout entire year, then a small difference in <kbd>Tab</kbd>'s behaviour is a detail which you have to fix and forget ;).

Comment: Fair enough..  Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

```
Use:
document.designMode = 'on';

Insted of 
body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
```